# What if we used extensible string in pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, string, elasticity

[image: Sample Image]

While I was solving questions,I saw that in most the questions, it's written that the used string in pulley is non-extensible,

**Why?**

**What would happen if we used extensible string having elasticity?**

Comment: "What would happen?" That's vague. Better is "how would the (some kinetic quantity) of X change"? By extensible, do you mean "elastic" or "extending at a constant rate of Y m/s"?

Answer (score 0):

In systems where different masses attach to each other by, in theory inelastic, strings, the constraint of constant string length applies. This allows the simplifying assumption that all parts of a string under tension have the same acceleration. This is because if they didn't, parts of the string would have relative acceleration and overtime would move away from each other thus stretching the string.

Mathematically, let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two points on a $1D$ string. Since the string is inelastic, $x_2-x_1=\text{const}.$ therefore $\ddot x_1=\ddot x_2$ and so the mag. of acceleration throughout the string is same.

Comment: May you kindly prove it mathematically? I'm having trouble to understand explanation without mathematical interpretation.

Comment: It's something you can just imagine. if you pull a string, one point will move just as fast as every other point. But if the string is elastic, it can warp when you pull it, like a gummy worm. And not all points move with the same speed at any given time.

Comment: If string is elastic, can we compare it with a spring?And for the above picture, acceleration for non-extensible string and extensible string will be same right? Just string will increase a bit in size in 2nd case.. Am I right?

Comment: @Sindid i was hoping to write a detailed answer but got busy.. a string is  like a one way spring, its restorative only under tension and limp under compression. For the given system, for the elastic case the acceleration of the hanging mass will reduce with time from its initial value as the string stretches while the tension in the string increases. For the mass on table, the acceleration would increase as the tension increases with time. This is unlike the inelastic case, where the tension and acceleration are constant, and the latter identical. Though I am not sure, they may be same at t=0

Comment: @Sindid $\ldots$ if the string is unstretched

Answer (score 0):

If the string can act like a spring, for the purpose of visualization and analysis, put then hanging mass on the friction-less horizontal surface with the other mass with a horizontal force equivalent with the weight. That force will determine the acceleration of the center of mass and each mass will act like it is pulled by a segment of spring from the center of mass.